# How can I double click the element with the same id, index and name in the list

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQRMG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYzIE.png)

Hello everyone. How can I click more than once on elements that have all the same properties?

My Code:

BasePage.java

```
public By parent = By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout");
public By children = By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Remove']");

protected List<WebElement> findChildrenOfParent(By parentBy, By childrenBy) {
    waitVisibility(parentBy);
    WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(parentBy);
    return parentElement.findElements(childrenBy);
}

protected void removeAllProductsFromCart(List<WebElement> elementList) {

    for (int i = 0; i < elementList.size(); i++) {
        elementList.get(i).click();
                   
    }
```

CartPage.java

```
public void deleteAllProductsBasket() throws InterruptedException {
                
    List<WebElement> childrenElements = findChildrenOfParent(parent, children);
    removeAllProductsFromCart(childrenElements);
            
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply click on these elements twice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elementList.size(); i++) {
    elementList.get(i).click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(300);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                   
    elementList.get(i).click();
}
```

I added a short sleep between the clicks to make it more stable

Comment: Possibly you are trying to use wrong elements. Possibly you should click on "TextView:remove" element? I can't know, need to debug that.